# How to add a usb slave port to a raspberry pi

Tags: usb, breadboard, cable

Is there a way,

- with a small board add-on,
- a simple cable incorporating some specialized chip,

to add a usb slave port to a RPi, to let it be used as a device?

Comment: The best thing is to use a USB to TTL/UART (Or USB to I2C) - THen you write the software/ API on the Pi. There isn't really anything where you can extend the Pi, and have it detected on Windows as a Pi and do stuff with, but maybe you can fill the market gap by developing something like that :)

Comment: or connect to something like a Teensy[https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/], that will show up on a host system as a HID device. Maybe you could explain why you need the functionality we can come up with another solution.

Comment: Yea it all depends on what you would like to do, like Rob says. PS Rob your link is dead.

Comment: The URL is fine, the ']' has been accidentally to the end of it though ;)

Comment: @rob, which Teensy version would you suggest ?  Can anybody suggest a tuto to capture (from within RPi) data exchanged between the Mini-B port and its Host ?

Answer (score 3):

Even though the USB port of the RPi is technically an On-the-go (OTG) chip that should support both a reduced set of host and client functionality the B/B+ type of the RPi does not support the device mode. That is related to the included USB hub and the fact that the ethernet is tunneled through USB ([see](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=15696)).

If everything else fails, there are examples of software based USB stacks to emulate an USB device on a microcontroller (e.g. the Igor Plug an IR remote control receiver based on an Atmel microcontroller). Of course such attempts only adress low-bandwith features such as human-interface devices (HIDs). If one desperately needs both USB host and device on a board with RPi capabilities one should also look into the BeagleBlack Bone boards.