# USB slave emulation

Tags: usb

I'm looking for a way to use raspberry as a slave usb device.

I noticed that the usb port of the model B/B+/2 is connected to a hub chip (as is the ethernet plug), and then to the processor, so the hardware prevent me from using it as slave, as discussed in [this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14911/how-to-add-a-usb-slave-port-to-a-raspberry-pi).

So, i start looking for an external USB chip that i could connect to the rasperry (UART / Serial most probably), and which i can entirely control : Computer <= USB => Chip <= Serial => Rpi

Every chip I found (here for example : http://www.ftdichip.com/) handle the USB protocol itself what I'm looking for, as I really need to do the usb stuff myself.

Do you know a chip that "convert" serial to male USB without handling USB protocol itself, or a USB chip i could program entirely (no protocol handling again, so no firmware ?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a usb slave port to a raspberry pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14911/how-to-add-a-usb-slave-port-to-a-raspberry-pi)

Comment: Hello and welcome! This is a very broad question. The chip that controls the USB in the funny gadgets is most likely USB-OTG in one fashion or the other. See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14911/how-to-add-a-usb-slave-port-to-a-raspberry-pi/23736#23736 if it helps you in any way. Feel free to rephrase your question with more details if need be.

Comment: I found out chips like teensy, which in fact do what i want : usb developement board, but using my raspberry would be better and much much simpler ! Any alternative comes to your minds ?

Comment: WRT USB sniffing, *you could at least make an effort and google this yourself*.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137206/how-do-i-intercept-messages-from-a-usb-device-on-linux  Please note this is a Q&A site, **not** a discussion forum.  I've tidied up and focused your question (*one at a time* please) on the issue you expressed interest in and removed the tangents and ramble.   Also consider: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378

Comment: @goldilocks - your edit made this question nothing but a pointless duplicate of http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14911/how-to-add-a-usb-slave-port-to-a-raspberry-pi  In the original form, at least it had some unique information about what the poster is trying to do.  **Please revert**, or failing that, close this as a duplicate.  In it's present form it is not a useful presence on the site.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get Synopsys to give you the reference manual of the USB block used in BCM283[56], you can rewrite the USB driver to support such operation. The Model A/A+ have its USB port exported directly from the Broadcom chip so if you get this to work you can test it without hacking the hardware.

Or you will need some sort of bridging mechanism like USB to Serial or USB slave to SPI slave adapter chips. The former is simple to implement and if you need more UART you can always use an NXP `SC16IS752` I2C UART chip (kernel driver included in latest Raspbian kernel). The latter option would also require you to acquire manuals of the chip and write a kernel driver.