# Easy Raspberry Pi Method of transferring picamera h264 files to computer

Tags: raspbian, data-transfer

I'm currently making a little video recording device using the RPi for someone who is not so tech savvy, although they are used to attaching a camera or sd card to the computer and pulling images and video to their home computer that way.

Can the RPi essentially just plug into a computer and boot up as an external drive (as if plugging in a usb)?  I'm sure it would take a bit to get it to work in that way but have not come across too much in my research.  For example ideally I would not want to have to plug a usb into the pi to get the files and then plug the usb into the destination computer.

They would be transferred onto a typical Mac or Windows computer from an un-networked Pi. I've read a few dropbox solutions but again I believe this is going to be an un-networked Pi.

Thanks for any help, suggestions, solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pi cannot operator as a USB slave device without additional hardware.

[USB slave emulation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/29621/usb-slave-emulation)
[Can I use Raspberry Pi as a USB peripheral device?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/271/can-i-use-raspberry-pi-as-a-usb-peripheral-device)

However as hard as I try I cannot find the device I have seen previously, pretty sure it was kickstarter or indiegogo.

The Raspberry Pi Model A might be an exception 
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=98&t=74098

Good luck and lets know how you get on.

Comment: I think instead to make my life easier I'll go with a enlisting an extra microSd card and usb adapter. That seems to be a smaller form factor and easy enough for the uninitiated to understand.